# store users activitie number in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to store user activitie in database as stats and I'm looking for an suggestion to achieve it and keep my database very optimized

I want to store those details:

> int: **member_id**, int: **today_activity**, int: **total_activity**

I'm thanking to update and increment total_activity  by 1 every time new activity set, I don't want to add new row for every activities. do you have any other suggestion or method to avoid inserting data for the same member_id to avoid making database size bigger?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a reporting table adding rows each time makes sense.

Comment: as I said, i don't want to insert each time new activity row from the same member_id Any other idea?

Comment: How big is your table ? Updating a large table is not advisable. You can achieve the you objective using upsert. If you table is small say few hundred thousands and have index on member_id you can consider updating it.